# How to rename android-debug.apk

Tags: android, cordova, config

I am using Cordova (5.1.1) and ionic framework to create my android. However, when I try to build the apk, why the file name is always "android-debug.apk" ? Is there any way to rename it ?

1. cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
2. cd hello
3. cordova platform add android
4. cordova build android

In the hello\config.xml, name tag is defined as HelloWorld already:

Please help.

Comment: What's your ide to build it?

Comment: I use cordova CLI to build only

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can change the name of the apk try this

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig getSigningConfig()
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
                    output.outputFile.name.replace("-debug", "-" + whatever name you want
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also sync and clean the project after this.

**Edit**

Write this in build.gradle file.

Comment: You can accept the answer then.. :) .So it can be helpful to others as well.

Comment: what file is this in?