# Cordova6.1 .1: how to rename android-debug.apk

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using Cordova(6.1.1) to create an android app.However, the output app build name is always "android-debug.apk".How to change the generated name.

I tried the way "[How to rename android-debug.apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177786/how-to-rename-android-debug-apk?answertab=votes#tab-top)".However, it doesn't work in Cordova 6.1.1.

Help me, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a cordova hook wich triggeres on "after_build" and rename the file.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html